# Prop not getting updated in child component on value change

Tags: vuejs2

In my `App` component (parent) I have:

```
<div class="bg-dark text-white text-center p-3 content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" v-model="dogBreed" />
        </div>
        <my-child-comp greeting="Hello from parent" v-bind:dog-breed="dogBreed" />
    </div>

...
data() {
        return {
            dogBreed: "Pit Bull"
        }
    },
```

And in the child view:

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-primary text-white text-center m-2 p-3 content">
        <h3>Dog: {{ dog }}</h3> 
    </div>
</template>

...
props: ["greeting", "dogBreed"], 
    data() {
        return {
            dog: this.dogBreed, 
        }
    },
```

I do get the initial value for `dogBreed` from the parent component inside of the child component, but when I change the value of the input field the same change is not reflected, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The prop in the parent component is not named properly, it should be the exact name of the props which is dogBreed you used in the child
>      component

```
<div class="bg-dark text-white text-center p-3 content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" v-model="dogBreed" />
        </div>
        <my-child-comp greeting="Hello from parent" v-bind:dogBreed="dogBreed" />
    </div>

...
data() {
        return {
            dogBreed: "Pit Bull"
        }
    },
```

> 2. Your child component can remain the same but use computed instead of data. Having the same name will not cause any computational
>      problems and using computed instead of data should fix up the dynamic
>      nature of your code.

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-primary text-white text-center m-2 p-3 content">
        <h3>Dog: {{ dog }}</h3> 
    </div>
</template>

    ...
 props: ["greeting", "dogBreed"], 
 computed: {
      dog(){
        return this.dogBreed
      }
   },
```

If however you are keen on using `dog-breed` then you must rename the prop in you child component to `dog-breed` before binding it in your parent component.

Comment: You're saying that the issue is that `v-bind:dog-breed="dogBreed"` should be `v-bind:dogBreed="dogBreed"` ? If so, that doesn't make a difference.